# Is there any way that we let the window appear but not the cmd in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am a beginner and developing a game in C++/SFML 2.1. I saw the examples like pong game which comes with SFML folder. Like in this game, the cmd window does not appear with game window.How can we do it in SFML?

Comment: If you're on Windows w/ VS just change the Subsystem to Windows and use WinMain. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SFML FAQ:](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/FAQ#wiki-tr-win-console)

> In Code::Blocks, open the project options (Project Menu -> Properties). In the Build targets tab, select the build target you wish to change on the left (most of the time only Debug and Release exist) and change its type option in the drop-down list on the right side from "Console application" to "GUI application".
>
> In Visual Studio, go to the project options (Project Menu ->
>   Properties). In the tree on the left, expand the "Configuration
>   properties" tree and expand the "Linker" sub-tree. Select "System"
>   from the sub-tree, and in the SubSystem field on the right side change
>   "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)" to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" by
>   clicking on the field and using the drop-down list.
>
> To maintain a portable entry point (int main() function), you can link
>   your program against the small sfml-main.lib library in the case of
>   Visual Studio or libsfml-main.a in the case of Code::Blocks/MinGW.
>
> Alternatively to hide the console, you can also define your own
>   Windows entry point for graphical applications.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
> LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
```

> Replace your int main() or int
>   main(int argc, char** argv) with this function and it will be called
>   by the operating system when your program is executed just like the
>   classical int main() function.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using GCC just add the `-mwindows` argument to your command:

The entire build command would then look something like this:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -I<sfml-install-path>/include -o main.o && g++ main.o -o build -I<sfml-install-path>/lib -mwindows -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```